# Cypress intercept - how to chain multiple assertions on a response

Tags: cypress

I just started using the new intercept method and have a basic question and want to know how to chain the two assertions below in one test.

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '/states').as('states');
cy.reload(true);
// cy.wait('@states').its('response.statusCode').should('eq',200)
cy.wait('@states').its('response.body').should('have.length', 50)
```

Both assertions work separately.

Answer (score 6):

The subject passed down from `.its('response.statusCode')` is the value of the `statusCode` property, so you need access to the `response` again to test both conditions

**Using closure to make `response` available to both assertions**

```js
cy.wait('@states')
  .its('response')
  .then(response => {
    cy.wrap(response).its('statusCode').should('eq', 200)     
    cy.wrap(response).its('body').should('have.length', 50)
  })
```

---

**Using the callback pattern**

```js
cy.wait('@states')
  .its('response')
  .should(response => expect(response.statusCode).to.eq(200))   
  .should(response => expect(response.body.length).to.eq(50))
```

---

**Re-reading the alias**

```js
cy.wait('@states')                                   // wait for the alias
  .its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200)

cy.get('@states')                                    // 2nd time use get()
  .its('response.body').should('have.length', 50)
```

Comment: btw- the only suggestion that worked was the last of the three.  The first two may work but may need to be tweaked a bit.  Thanks for the help! Much appreciated!

Comment: I tried the 1st one, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Works like a charm:

```
cy.intercept("POST", "/graphql").as("someInterception");  

cy.wait("@someInterception").then(({ request, response }) => {
  expect(response.body.data.someField).to.be.true;
  expect(request.body.variables.someField).to.be.true;
});
```

See: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Using-the-yielded-object

Comment: Question already answered.